# Best way to preserve display only properties

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I know that if you have hidden fields or editable/input controls that the values get bound on postback to your viewmodel.

however, for other things like for example "Description" or "Title" properties you could have in a model which are just display only, they will not get posted back. Makes sense.

But what if you wanted them to be bound on POST, what is the best way of doing this? The reason I ask is because what if the view model has errors, you would return back the model to the view but the model will not contain the string for "Description" or "title" so when the model is being bound to the view - its empty.

Rather than having to do a call out to the database again (overhead), what is the best way to still preserve these display only items?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you have two options:

1) use hidden values for these properties

2) load state from database

Usually this situation is rare, and I mostly use first option, but sometimes the second one.

Comment: Agreed. The problem with the first one is that the data/DOM would be more bloated. The problem with the second one is the overheads.